# Client-side JavaScript in Birt report library

Tags: birt

I am trying to solve the following problem in `Birt` reporting - when I display the date in `Dynamic Text` which is taken from the query parameters, I want to call JavaScript function which will transform this date into some user-friendly  form. So I do something like

`getTextDate(params["fromDate"].value)`

and I have my scripts in `initialize`. This works fine.

But my question is, when I make a library with reusable elements and I want to employ JavaScript functions like the one above, how can I do this?`initialize` is not available in library template and wasn't able to find other way how to inlude JS. [This](http://www.lebirtexpert.com/wordpress/2010/08/03/javascript-functions-lib/) article wasn't helpfull for me because I want client-side functions, not server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, it's enough to create JS file with the common functions and put it into Shared Resources and then add it to the Resources of the library itself.